# Big O notation of adding and removing elements from Array

Tags: big-o

so I'm quite sure that adding elements to an Array (and doubling the capacity once the maximum is reached) has the Big-O-Notation O(n). Same with removing elements, and halving capacity once only half the capacity or less is filled with elements.

When combining add and remove operations on the same array I think the Big-O-Notation would be O(n) as well.

So my question is would there be any worse scenario than O(n)?

Comment: "Big O" is only (somewhat) relevant when discussing time complexity of things, measured in the number of abstract operations. As soon as you start to dissect those "operations" closer, the whole concept falls apart and becomes some abstract unhelpful unit completely irrelevant for the purpose of determining performance in terms of execution speed. Accessing arrays is too close to the metal for "Big O" to hold relevance.